# Accept Integer Input in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, input, keyboard, console-application

Can someone please tell me how to read a set of integers from the keyboard for a console application using Swift?

I have tried the following method:

```
func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return (NSString(data: inputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String)
}
```

But this function will treat the entered value as a string.
And converting the string to Int results in a nil value.

Is there is anything similar to scanf() or cin() like in C, C++ ?

Comment: What you actually want to achieve, do you want number pad keyboard ?

Comment: Well, I am actually writing a console application in Swift where I need to accept integers from the keyboard.

Comment: If you want user to enter only integers, you can change keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad.

Comment: @Ashish : I ain't working on an iOS application. Currently solving a problem in hackerrank where I need to accept a set of integers from the keybard. So i just want to know if there is anything similar to scanf() like in C

Answer (score 1):

**1. If Statements and Forced Unwrapping**

```
var number:Int?
print("Enter a number")
number = Int(readLine()!)
if number != nil{
    print("The entered number is", number!)
}
else{
    print("The input is not a number")
}
```

Declare an optional Int variable or constant. Use readLine() to input number, readLine() returns string so we have to do type conversion using Int(). We have to unwrap the return value of readLine() by using "!". If the input entered is a number, the number will be converted to Int and stored in the variable "number" else nil will stored in optional Int variable "number".

**2. Simplified version of above code**

```
print("Input a number: ")
if let input = Int(readLine()!){
    print("The entered number is", input)
}
else{
    print("The input is not a number")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert ur result to int like this : **Int**(string) //swift 2.0

or

Try this :

```
var intVal:Int
if let i = readLine(stripNewline: true){ //keyboard
intVal = Int(i)!
}
```